# Working with constructors and extremely confused

Tags: java, constructor

This is my first time trying to do anything with "constructors" and after an hour or so of looking around for help on this topic, I still feel like I have no idea what I am doing.

So here is a class file that I created for a different program, and its supposed to have 2 constructors. I tried my best, but compiler kept telling me I need identifiers.

How do I identify the constructors?

```
   public class property
{
int storey = 0;
int width = 0;
int length = 0;

    property(int storey, int width, int length)
    {
        {
        this.storey = storey;
        this.width = width;
        this.length = length;
        }

    }

    property(int width, int length)
    {
        this(1, width, length);

    }


    public int calculateArea(int area)
    {

        return (storey * width * length);

    }

    public double calculatePrice(double price)
    {

       return (((storey * width * length) * 2.24) *1.15);

    }

}
```

Comment: p1 and p2 need to have data types: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: As the answers show, you need data types for your contructor parameters, but I suspect you also want multiple parameters too. It looks like you are assigning the member valiables storey, width and length their default values. That doesn't seem right. I suspect you meant to pass those values into the constructor.

Comment: What are p1 and p2. If they are variable then declare those first.

Comment: declare the datatypes of p1 and p2, and also override the multiple constructors with different type and no. of arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that you need to specify what type the `p1` and `p2` variables should be.  For example:

```
property(int p1)
{
  // constructor
}
```

Some other advice:

- Class names should be upper camel case, i.e. `Property`.
- Both constructors are assigning fields to themselves, you should specify `storey`, `width`, and `length` as constructor arguments, then use the `this` keyword to assign them to fields:

```
Property(int storey, int width, int length)
{
  this.storey = storey;
  this.width = width;
  this.length = length;
}
```

- When you want to default values in a constructor then you can call other constructors:

```
Property(int width, int length)
{
  this(1, width, length);
}
```

- `calculateArea` and `calculatePrice` should return the calculated values.  Assigning to a parameter will have no effect:

```
public int calculateArea()
{
    return (storey * width * length);
}
```

- Add accessors for the property's fields:

```
public int getStorey()
{
    return storey;
}
```

You can then use your property like:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(System.in); 
System.out.println("storey: ");     
int storey = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 

System.out.println("width: ");     
int width = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 

System.out.println("length: "); 
int length = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 

Property p = new Property(storey, width, length); 
System.out.println("property dimensions:width " + p.calculateArea()); 
System.out.println("width: " + p.getWidth()); 
System.out.println("length: " + p.getLength()); 
System.out.println("storeys: " + p.getStoreys()); 
System.out.println("area: " + p.calculateArea());
System.out.println("price: " + p.calculatePrice());
```

Comment: But I can't give values to the storey width and height...like they are being entered into another program that uses the property class

Comment: @user1965245, I'm not sure I understand your problem.  Perhaps you could expand on how you want to use your property class?

Comment: I'm using the property class to assign variables to the storey width and length, as well as to calculate area and price. In my actual program, the user enters 3 values, one for storey width and height, and then the program calculates the area and price.

Comment: So you would have something like:

`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(System.in);
System.out.println("storey: ");
int storey = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
System.out.println("width: ");
int width = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
System.out.println("length: ");
int length = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
Property p = new Property(storey, width, length);
System.out.println("area: " + p.calculateArea());`

Comment: I tried this, the compiler kept saying it could not find the symbol for calculateArea and calculatePrice

Comment: Probably because you declared the two methods with parameters.  Have you tried making the changes that I've suggested?  If so, could you update the question with your current code?

Comment: As I said, you need to remove the arguments to `calculateArea` and `calculatePrice`.

Comment: My assignment says i need to have a behavior/method called calculateArea and another called calculatePrice

Comment: Sure, but neither should take an argument.  Please see how I've defined `calculateArea()`, not `calculateArea(int area)`.

Comment: now the section in my other code for the program where i use Property p = new Property(storey, width, length); is giving me "cannot find symbol" error, because its looking for storey width and length in the program's class instead of property class :/

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example of how you access the property's values.

Comment: I'm still getting cannot find symbol errors for p.getWidth and storey and length. Just those 3 errors.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30764/discussion-between-simonc-and-user1965245)

Answer (score 1):

The constructor needs to know what type `p1` and `p2` are. And you would probably want to do something with those values, e.g. you could assign the values of p1 or p2 to either width or length.

You've written `if(storey >> 1)` - don't you mean `if (storey > 1)`?

Also I would provide some default values for the constructor in case `storey` isn't 1. Like:

```
property(int s, int w, int l)
{
    if (l > 1)
    {
        storey = s;
        width = w;
        length = l;
    }
    else
    {
        storey = 0;
        width = 0;
        length = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: all i need it to do is figure out if storey is 1 or if storey is bigger than 1.

Comment: But if storey is initially 0, how can it ever be 1 upon initialisation? Take a look at the code I've added with my edit. And for testing if something is bigger than another value you would need the `>` sign, `>>` is right bit shifting and does something completely different.

Comment: Here's a good SO explanation of what a good constructor should look like:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579445/java-constructors

It is standard practice to declare the member variables (storey, width, length) private and have getters and setters to modify them (but only once the object has been created), an SO explanation:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/tutorial-on-getters-and-setters

The member variables would be assigned values by the constructor upon initialising the object, it's good to have several different constructors depending on how many arguments you are passing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify type of your argument of constructors, here `p1` and `p2`

for example:

```
property(int p2)
```

Comment: now it is saying property(int) is already defined in class property for property(int p2)

Comment: You need to overload constructor, how would java know which one to execute if you have same signature for both of them ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to specify datatypes.How the compiler know which type they are

```
 property(p1)
```

Example:      `property(int p1)`

Answer (score 0):

The `p1` and `p2` you pass into your constructors need to have a type associated with them. So you would this:

```
public property(int p1)
{
    //do something
}
```