# Looping through a class instance's enum

Tags: java, enums

I want to create a new instance of a class (that contains an `enum`).
Then I want to loop through this instance's `enum`.

Is this possible and if so how?

Edit:
  Instance? I think I needed to learn some more java then.
  The correct question and awnser is at [[click me].](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128551/someenum-vals-someenum-values-varible-changing-after-defined)

Comment: You should learn a little about classes . See that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579445/java-constructors

Comment: Your question is unclear (at least for me). You asked "Can I somehow send data to a class?" but then you answered it with `SomeClass sc = new SomeClass("Lightspeed");` so you already know how to send data to *instance of class*. It looks more like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) than real question, so maybe try to explain what you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: An enum is a representation of something (like an int or string) with a variable name. You don't send data to it, you use the enum as a reference. An enum is a data type.

Comment: I got the constructor I just need how to set a method inside the class then have the enum get said varible like: Account(varibleHere); Then looping thru this enum and doing stuff with it ready to be used again.  **Do you get exactly what I'm asking?**

Comment: I also don't understand your question. An enum doesn't (typically) have method logic. It is usually a named constant datatype.

Comment: ***Question edited*** Sorry for the other question this one should be easier to understand and awnser ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public SomeClass(String name){ SomeEnum.PlayerName.value = name}

This allows me to do what I need.