# SomeEnum[] vals = SomeEnum.values() varible changing after defined?

Tags: java, enums

```
PlayerDefaults[] pds;
if (pds == null)
{
    pds = PlayerDefaults.values();
}
PlayerDefaults.Name.value = "Lightspeed360";
```

It sets perfectly before Name is set to "Lightspeed360" then changes to it after defined?
I'm so confused please explain/help.
[ALL CODE here](http://pastie.org/pastes/10615569/text?key=mhncmbxofzpzapqpqb7ka)
Here is the Log I get from running the code you see above:

```
TEST BEFORE> $Name$
TEST BEFORE> 2000
TEST BEFORE> 0
TEST AFTER> Lightspeed360
TEST AFTER> 2000
TEST AFTER> 0
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more code? Like... class definition of PlayerDefaults and how you check it's changed?

Comment: I had a loop going thru the array before Name is set then after I see that it changes to name after it's set after the array was set?

Comment: I cannot decompile your code from that. Please share it.

Comment: Added how I see the difference in description under "Some Test Code."

Comment: Your first block of code does not compile. Because of definite assignment, you can't compare an uninitialized local variable to null.

Comment: How can I fix this? I mean it sets and is initialized once then it changes. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your enum' values are not changing.

It's just that some member-variables of those enum values (which you happened to name `value`) are changing. Which is not a good thing from a design perspective, but it's legal.

You will not be able to *add items* to the enum that way - that would break the enum contract.

In fact, enums can be a lot like classes in Java. Some even like them for Singletons (although that's not the greatest of ideas). So you can have member variables, methods and a lot of other stuff. But you'll always have only a limited number of items - the ones you enumerated at the beginning of the enum declaration.

Check this change to your debug-output:

```
    for (PlayerDefaults pd : pds)
    {
        System.out.println("Name before> " + pd.name());
        System.out.println("TEST BEFORE> " + pd.value);
    }
    PlayerDefaults.Name.value = name;
    for (PlayerDefaults pd : pds)
    {
        System.out.println("Name after> " + pd.name());
        System.out.println("TEST AFTER> " + pd.value);
    }
```

You still get the same enum objects - which are uniquely identified by their `name()`.

**Edit regarding your question**

How about:

```
public static enum PlayerDefaults
{

    Name("$Name$"),
    Money(2000),
    Warnings(0);

    public static void reset() {
        Name.value = "$Name";
        Money.value = 2000;
        Warnings.value = 0;
    }
```

So now if you need to *reset* your enum, you can do so. **BUT** this cries "I'm not thread-safe". What if while you're setting it to one value, someone else in another thread resets...?

It might be better to keep a `Map<PlayerDefaults,Object>` in your code and limit the `PlayerDefaults` to represent the names of the defaults only and not the values as well.

**Example using Map**

Consider this example using the values only for intializing a Map:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DataDefaults
{

    Map<PlayerDefaults, Object> playerData = new HashMap<PlayerDefaults,Object>();

    public DataDefaults(final String name)  {
        if (playerData.isEmpty())
        for (PlayerDefaults pd : PlayerDefaults.values()) {
            playerData.put(pd, pd.value);           
        }
        playerData.put(PlayerDefaults.Name, name);      
    }

    void close() {
        for(Map.Entry<PlayerDefaults, Object> entry : playerData.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey().name() + ": " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public static enum PlayerDefaults { 
        Name("$Name$"),
        Money(2000),
        Warnings(0);

        private Object value; 
        private PlayerDefaults(Object value) {
            this.value = value;
        }       

        Object getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DataDefaults("WTF");
    }
}
```

Comment: So is there any other way to "reset" my enum?

Comment: Yes it says the name before the value(I don't know the proper name) set . . . Can you explain a bit about your edit?

Comment: What part needs more explaining? The reset or the Map thing?

Comment: I didn't see the second edit give me a second. Ok yes I can reset it that way but, I would like to get all values save them then when I'm done set all values inside enum to what was saved first like I say above.

Comment: Ok I get $Name$ in my hashmap but, it's a little wonky it goes Name > warnings > money when in enum it's Name>Money>Warns    Nevermind I fixed that.

Comment: so... who cares? If you absolutely need order maintained, you could loop (again) over enum values and perform map.get() on those.

Comment: How can I set it to the items in the hashmap? I got everything to work but, I'm tired and can't figure out how i would. :L

Comment: set what to the values in the hashmap? Sorry, I'm still not sure what you want to *do* with the playerData later on.

Comment: Ok thank you I got it to reset like I want and everything! I would +1 this but, my rep died yesteryday asking another question for this enum to get $name$ to be what I wanted in consturctor. :P This is a "constructor" for a player data/stats yml.

Comment: Never mind I got up to 15 then rip to 8 but, i still got the privillage. :D No more 100 lines of ymlCrap.set(StringPath, a object). A nice enum to create that all for me.

Comment: Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

Each enumeration in the PlayerDefaults in your example PlayerDefaults.Name is like

```
public static final PlayerDefaults Name = new PlayerDefaults();
```

So whenever you access the PlayerDefaults.Name, you'll get the same object.

For more detail of how to use enum, I suggest you to read "Effective Java" chapter 6

### EDIT:

The reason why you can access PlayerDefaults.Name.value directly inside the DataDefaults is because PlayerDefaults is an inner enum of DataDefaults.
You can consider each PlayerDefaults as a static member of DataDefaults.
Since the whole class is under your control, it is your responsibility that not let any value of field of a PlayerDefaults be changed.

Comment: I don't get exactly what you mean if you'd like the whole class go here: http://pastie.org/pastes/10615569/text?key=mhncmbxofzpzapqpqb7ka

Comment: In general, it' should not allow anyone to change the values of fields inside the enum.

Comment: The thing is I got it to kinda work before but, not what I wanted so I removed it and now can't get it to work again.