# How to call the method correctly

Tags: java, string, class, methods, static

I posted this kind of question earlier but i got negative respond because i didn't showing my try. So i post this again including my try and i still don't get how method in Java works.
This is my try:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MethodTest {

    public static exception(String name) {

        if (name == Abudi) {
            System.out.println("Your " + name + " is not allowed to proceed");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        exception pc = new exception();
        String name;
        System.out.print("Enter your name here: "); name = sc.nextLine();

        pc.exception(name);
    }
}
```

How do I call the `exception` method correctly?
Thanks.

Comment: There are several (a lot actually) problems with your code. I may suggest you read a basic Java Tutorial before beginning coding.

Comment: @Yassin Hajaj Yeah i am relatively new to programming world. Thanks tho.

Comment: I believe the name "exception" is a reserved word on java. Try and change the name of your method into something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at this program. It only takes input once and close. But you will be able to understand how the method works.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExceptionTest {

    public static void exception(String name) {

        if (name.equals("Abudi")) {
            System.out.println("Your " + name + " is not allowed to proceed");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //exception1(sc.next());
        String name;
        System.out.print("Enter your name here: "); 
        name = sc.nextLine();

        exception(name);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the class name, because `static` method is common for all instances of that class.

```
MethodTest.exeption(name);
```

Or just in case your method is owned by a class it's called from.

```
exeption(name);
```

Actually the return statement is missing. If you don't return anything, use `void`.

```
public static void exception(String name) {
    ...
}
```

And remove the following line `exception pc = new exception();`. It makes no sence because methods are not constructed at all.

In general, calling `static` methods doesn't require calling constructor of class before and creating instance. `static` methods are not fixed on instances.

---

Finally the body of your `main` method would look like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your name here: "); 
String name = sc.nextLine();
exception(name);
```

Comment: And remove the line `exception pc = new exception()` as it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are calling your `exception` "method" as a constructor. You can read more about constructors [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579445/java-constructors).

To make your `exception` method work, first you need to define it correctly, by setting the return type to `void`. This means that the method does not return anything.

```
public static void exception(String name) {
    if (name == "Abudi") {
        System.out.println("Your " + name + " is not allowed to proceed.");
    }
}
```

Then, to call this method, use:

```
MethodTest.exception(name); /* If you are calling it from another class */
```

or just:

```
exception(name); /* If you are calling this static method from its own class */
```

Comment: So the syntax is always <class where this is written>.<method>(..) if i call it from that class?

Comment: If you are calling it from a class that does not contain the static method you want to call, use `SomeClass.someMethod(...)` call.
Else if you are calling the static method from the class where that method is located, you can use just `someMethod(...)`, but it is not wrong to make the call as said above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call the method outside the MethodTest class you need to do:

```
MethodTest methodtest = new MethodTest();

methodtest.exception(name);
```

Or if you want to call the method inner the MethodTest class you need to do:

```
exception(name);
```

You need simply to call the method `exception(String name)` in the method `main(String[] args)` doing:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    System.out.print("Enter your name here: ");
    name = sc.nextLine();

    exception(name);

}
```