# use constructors to create a text file and take user input for filename

Tags: java, file

main Class Which is accepting user input as a file name.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        FileOperator fileObject = new FileOperator();
        System.out.println(Strings.userMenu);
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = scan.next();
        if(userInput.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println(Strings.inputExpected);
        }
        else{           
            fileObject.fileOperator(userInput);
        }

    }
}

/* It is a generic file which takes user input as a file name and saves the file with that name.*/

public class FileOperator {

/*
 * The Below Method fileOperator will access filename as a input from user.
 * Checks if the file is available in given path.
 * If File is available then file exist message will be printed.
 * Else new file with that name will b created.
 * If user enters nothing then error message will be popped up.
 */

    public  void fileOperator(String userInputFileName) throws Exception { 

            File newFileName = new File(userInputFileName);

        if(newFileName.exists() && !newFileName.isDirectory()) { 
            System.out.println(Strings.fileExists);
        }
        else if (newFileName.createNewFile()){
                System.out.println(Strings.fileCreated);
              }
        else if(newFileName.equals("")){
            System.out.println("");
        }

        else{
                 System.out.println(Strings.errorForFileNotCreated);
            }
    }
}
```

But the problem is I want to create a file object using a constructor. I am very new to java so kindly help with this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579445/java-constructors

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Aren't you already using constructor in `File newFileName = new File(userInputFileName);` ? Didn't understood your question.

Comment: i want do this using java coding standards were i need to create constructors in different class or package. how is that done???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create constructor in FileOperator class:

```
public class FileOperator{
    public FileOperator(String filename){
          // here write fileOperator method code and delete that method
      }
}
in main delete FileOperator fileObject = new FileOperator(); // and write in else part 
{
  FileOperator fileObject = new FileOperator(userInput)
}
```