# How Do I Make A Class Take Arguments?

Tags: java

So, I have the class ScalingDraw and I want it to accept two arguments into it when its called, 'int width' and 'int height'.

```
public class ScalingDraw() extends JPanel {}
```

Intuitively, I thought that it would be like

```
public class ScalingDraw(int width, int height) extends JPanel {}
```

and to call it I would use

```
ScalingDraw SD = new ScalingDraw(width, height);
```

however I receive an error, and I checked the documentation, and I did not see much that helped me in the field of understanding my problem.

Comment: You're looking for how to write constructors. The class itself doesn't take arguments.

Comment: @downvoters: Come on people, this is a perfectly valid question for a beginner. It is well written, understandable and within the scope of Stackoverflow. Just because it's easy to answer, or would give plenty of solutions if OP knew to search for "constructor", doesn't mean it's bad or needs downvoting. We should mark this as duplicate of [Java Constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/579445/9199167), but let it live, so other beginners who search with similar terminology can find it.

Comment: You really need to read that lecture again. Search for `constructors` they are used for making instance of class which is called object. And you can have empty construct and multiple constructors that take arguments which you are searching for. Then learn about getters and setters, abstract classes and interfaces. Search for polymorhism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a constructor. A constructor is a special method within a class used to create an instance of it, and which can accept parameters which you can use for anything.

In your case, you would have this constructor:

```
public ScalingDraw(int width, int height){
     // Do whatever you need here, like assigning those prameters to class fields.
}
```

You can have as many constructors as required in a class, as long as they have different parameters. Note, though, constructors have no return type (not even void).