# Values are always returning null after building object

Tags: java

The idea is to print out a simple line saying the book title, author, and price. However, I cannot seem to return any value even after constructing a Book object.

I'm building a Book class, an Author class, and using a Tester to run the program.

Here's what I'm looking at:

```
package book;

public class Book {

    String title;
    Author author;
    double price;

    public Book(String title, Author author, double price){}

    public Book(){}

    public void setbookTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Author getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

}
```

```
package book;

public class Author {

    String name;
    String email;
    char gender;

    public Author(String name, String email, char gender){
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

    public char getGender(){
        return gender;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setGender(char gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }



}
```

```
package book;

public class BookTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Author author1 = new Author("Horstmann", "horstmann@gmail.com", 'm');
    Book book1 = new Book("Big Java", author1, 60);

    Double number = book1.getPrice();
        System.out.println(number);

    System.out.println ("The Book information is: ");
    System.out.println(book1.getTitle() + book1.getAuthor() + book1.getPrice());


    }

}
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: your never calling setbookTitle, setName, setPrice, etc. They do not get set automatically, you have to program it to do what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579445/java-constructors)

Comment: Does the author1 and book1 not use setBookTitle or setName?

Comment: Oh I see it now... I'm a dummy. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is null because you didn't do anything in your Book's & Author's constructor:

```
public Author(String name, String email, char gender){
}

public Book(String title, Author author, double price){
}
```

You need to set the value and update it into your object's value:

```
public Author(String name, String email, char gender){
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.gender = gender;
}

public Book(String title, Author author, double price){
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.price = price;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see it now... I'm a dummy. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

you should change the Constructor to

```
public Book(String title, Author author, double price){
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this. price = price;
}

public Author(String name, String email, char gender){
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.gender = gender;
}
```