# Java error: Cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, class, object

So I'm quite new to Java and this is the first time I'm working with objects.
Could you help me out with why this piece of code doesn't work?

```
public class Object
{
    String a1;
    String[] a2;
    int a3;
    double a4;
    long a5;
}
```

And here is the main class:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Object obj1 = new Object("example text", new String[] {"some", "more", "examples", "here"}, 1, 1.0);
    }
}
```

Error message:

**java: constructor Object in class Object cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found:    java.lang.String,java.lang.String[],int,double
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length**

Comment: `Object` is a built-in type. Call your class something else. And if you want to pass arguments to `new`, write a constructor in it.

Comment: Check also the javadocs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Comment: Sorry, I used "Object" just as an example name to make it more understandable. In my actual code I used a different name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579445/java-constructors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare a ***constructor*** for your `Object` class inside it as:

```
public class Object {
    String a1;
    String[] a2;
    int a3;
    double a4;
    long a5;

    public Object(String example_text, String[] strings, int i, double v) {
    }
}
```

And another important thing is that `Object` is a predefined class in Java, so you should use *full package name* of your own `Object` class in main method:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Object obj1 = new path.to.Object("example text", new String[] {"some", "more", "examples", "here"}, 1, 1.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: `Object` is not a keyword. But your point stands and your suggestion about namespacing it makes sense. Even better, don't import it but refer to it with its full package name to avoid confusion (`var obj1 = path.to.Object("example text", new String[] {"some", "more", "examples", "here"}, 1, 1.0);`). Even better-er *don't* call your own class `Object` :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the name of your class, since Java already has a class name Object or add a constructor for your Class. Use for example the name **MyObject.java**